# Export to excel not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, export-to-excel

I have a table that I am trying to export.  My goal is to also preserve CSS applied to the table, so that it appears in excel exactly (or really close) to how it looks on the page.  I am using this function:

```
function exportToExcel( container ) {
    var begin = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" ' +
        'xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head>' +
        '<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>SlideIdTool</x:Name>"' +
        '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets>' +
        '</x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body>';
    var end = '</body></html>';
    window.open( 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent( begin + $( container ).html() + end ) );
}
```

This works great in Chrome and Firefox.  But it doesn't work in IE 9 or 10.  I see a window pop up but no content, no request to download anything, nada.  In chrome, it downloads straight to a file, with no popup window or anything.

Any suggestions on tweaks or fixes to get cross browser functionality out of this function?

Comment: Have you tried: window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $(container).html());

Comment: @AxGryndr yep, exact same behavior.

Comment: How about creating an ActiveXObject of the Excel.Application type and exporting that way?

Comment: I think I might have to do that- detect browser type and all.  Super gross though.

Comment: True - sucks having to support multiple browsers because there are subtle differences.